# count number of elements with a list that also contains a list

Tags: python, list, element

```
>>> a = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
>>> print(len(a))
4
```

The length of the list is 4, why is the element count 4 and not 5?

Comment: @nbro no need to be mean

Comment: @meda `mean`? Who? Never heard about joking? I am always joking if I am not.

Comment: we all think like this while learning some new stuffs.

Comment: gotta start off somewhere nbro! sorry i'm not as advanced in python as you are. Thanks

Comment: @Python_rookie I am not advanced. Maybe you are more than me :D

Comment: Wow what's with all the downvotes and snarky comments? This is the kind of thing that turns people away from so and asking for help in general.

Comment: @Python_rookie: nbro is being a troll, just ignore those comments. I have flagged them, they are not acceptable here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't believe you are flagging me. What did I do?

Comment: @mnjeremiah The downvoting reasons are obvious: lack of research. People should ask for help, but 90% of SO nowadays is people asking for help before even trying anything. No one even reads their own stack trace. This is not the case here though, and the confusion is somewhat legitimate, it's just a bit hasty to post a question.

Comment: @keyser, completely disagree on this post. He posted his code and asked a legit question. Isn't that what this place is for.

Comment: @mnjeremiah I think this question is too elementary and is certainly duplicated.

Comment: @nbro, maybe elementary for you. If it's a duplicate, post the link to the duplicate question. That would be much more helpful than asking someone if they are 10, etc... anyway, that's all I have to say. Happy Holidays. :)

Comment: @mnjeremiah We seem to have different views on how much research someone should do before asking. This question is in many regards a legitimate question though, as you say. If it's too elementary or not is in the eye of the beholder. (Personally I didn't downvote). Happy holidays!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element count in the **outer** list is 4. `a[2]` is **one object**. It doesn't matter here that that one object is also a list.

If you need to count the number of elements *recursively*, then do so yourself:

```
def recursive_element_count(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        return sum(recursive_element_count(elem) for elem in ob)
    # anything that isn't a list counts as one element
    return 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> def recursive_element_count(ob):
...     if isinstance(ob, list):
...         return sum(recursive_element_count(elem) for elem in ob)
...     return 1
... 
>>> a = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
>>> recursive_element_count(a)
5
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why you add `return 1` at the last?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: because each non-list element counts as 1 item.

Answer (score 1):

As the inner list assumed as one object the `len` returned 4  . you can use the following code for calculate the length of all elements :

```
>>> a = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
>>> sum(len(i) if isinstance(i,list) else 1 for i in a)
5
```

`isinstance()` function used for check the type of object .

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep , surely ,we could do it with a recursion function for another levers .

Answer (score 1):

Do you know sets from mathematic? That's similar in Python, in lists-tuples-sets etc. if there is a list in list or tuple in tuple etc. they are one element.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3]
a.append(b)
print (a)
print (len(a))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[1, 2, 3, [2, 3]]
4
>>>
```

Thats because *len(a)=4*. [2,3] is an element of `list(a)`.